# Subset a data set for only new individuals after a certain time (R)

Tags: r, subset

my data frame contains information for many individuals over a time period. New individuals are added to the data frame as they appear.

i want to subset my data frame for a time period so that only new individuals appear.
eg. data frame from 2000-2012. subset for 2008-2012 and only include individuals who appear in 2008-2012 but not 2000-2008

more info:

my data set looks a little like this

data

```
id date score
43 2006 15
12 2011 15
12 2007 16
14 2011 17
14 2011 14
14 2012 14
```

i want to subset so that only id's which have their first appearance after 2008 are included. 
i.e in the above example only id=14 would be included as all scores occur after 2008. id=12 would not be included because one score occurred pre-2008

Comment: Please show a small example dataset to understand the problem better.

Comment: Did you mean individuals who appear in `2008-2012` but not `2000-2007`?

Comment: Yes, individuals who appear in 2008-2012 but not 2000-2007

Comment: My code works on the example you showed.  Please check `Update2` on my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `date` column

```
 Year <- as.numeric(format(datN$Date, "%Y"))
 indx <- Year %in% 2008:2012
 datN[indx,][!datN$ID[indx] %in% datN$ID[!indx],]
 #   ID       Date
 #4  11 2009-02-09
 #17  4 2012-02-14
 #19 11 2009-08-23
 #40 20 2010-11-20
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
datN <- data.frame(ID= sample(1:20, 50, replace=TRUE),
 Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2012-12-31'), by=1), 50, replace=FALSE))
```

#### Update2

```
 indx <- dat$date %in% 2008:2012
 dat[indx,][!dat$id[indx] %in% dat$id[!indx],]
 #   id date score
 #4 14 2011    17
 #5 14 2011    14
 #6 14 2012    14
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(43L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L), date = c(2006L, 
2011L, 2007L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L), score = c(15L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 14L, 14L)), .Names = c("id", "date", "score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I would make sure your date field is formatted as a date field. 
Once that is done, there are numerous ways to do it.

one way is to subset based on specific dates:

`foo <- bar[bar$date>as.Date("2008-01-01") & bar$date<as.Date("2012-12-31"),]`

You can also extract the year, and save that as an additional column, as a plain number, and use that. I think the first way gives you more flexibility.